# node.js ENOTFOUND getaddrinfo

Tags: node.js

I know that I'm not the only one who ask this kind of questions here.
I find article here, it seem to be that it can't find ip address that I ordered with DNS, and it's usually cause by a wrong host name.
I originally use http.request, I want to get "http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/26677/feed.json"
the option part I write like this:

```
var option = {
    host: 'api.thingspeak.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/channels/26677/feed.json',
    method: 'GET'
};
```

Than it show thw wrong message 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND'
I think I didn't ordered a wrong host(maybe).
Finally I tried using http.get, and the codelike this:

```
var http = require('http');

function get_data_from_thingspeak(){

    var str = [];

    var callback = function(response) {
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str.push(chunk);
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(str.join(''));
        });
        response.on('error', function(e) {
          console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
        });
    };
    http.get("http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/26677/feed.json", callback);

}
```

So why?
I can use chorme access this page by "http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/26677/feed.json"

but can't do that with node?

Where's the problem I miss?

Comment: it works fine on my computer. Just use this `http.get(option, callback);` is also ok.

Comment: I tried it again but failed, this time I use http.get(option, callback), the contain of option is as what I write above, it fail with same problem